# Is Magento 2.4.5-p5 compatible with MariaDB 10.6.16?

Tags: mariadb

Is Magento 2.4.5-p5 compatible with MariaDB 10.6.16?
I am runing Magento 2.4.5-p5 on a Centos 7 Server running MariaDB 10.4.  We are preparing for a move to AlmaLinux OS 8.
I am trying to upgrade some Amasty Extensions on the Centos 7 server and the Extensions require MariaDB 10.6.16.  I am told by my Server Tech Support, if I ungrade to MariaDB 10.6.16 I cannot go back to MariaDB 10.4.  Thanks for your help...

Thank you,
Richard Wendrock

Answer (score 0):

The Magento Core team (Adobe) officially tested and supported MariaDB 10.2-10.4 for Magento 2.4.5. However, the community has experienced like you in the past, and they have applied the customization or a patch to make Magento allow MariaDB 10.6. I also used MariaDB 10.6 for Magento 2.4.5 on a few projects, and it works as expected.

You can override the `MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)` value of the `supportedVersionPatterns` argument within the `Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\SqlVersionProvider` type declaration in your custom module.

File path: `app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml`.
Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\SqlVersionProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="supportedVersionPatterns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)" xsi:type="string">^10\.[2-6]\.</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```